# Missing hot corners and Dock keeps defaulting

Tags: macos, dock, settings

I recently installed a Jamf software in order to recieve the latest MS Office, and during the installation the dock was reset to the default preferences.

After installation I went to customize my dock by removing and adding apps to the dock, setting the magnification zoom, and auto hide. This is when I noticed Hot corners didn't work too.

This is where the problem starts – I tried to set the hot corner settings, but the moment I press the back button or exit out of settings, it doesn't save the settings.

I have tried PRAM and SMC resets, removing Jamf files, resetting home folder and ALCs, repairing disk permissions in recovery mode, trying hot corners in safe mode (which it still doesn't work) and killing the Dock and SystemUIServer in terminal with no avail.

After trying all of these, turning on the macbook back to normal, the hot corners still doesn't work, and also the dock has resetted back to it's default settings again.

Is there any help to this? I feel uncomfortable using the keyboard, dock or using the 4 finger pinch to access launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally found an answer that resolved my Hotcorners and resetting dock.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/22421052#22421052

The first two helpful comments were what solved my trivia.

Basically,

1. Head over to ~/Library/Preferences and delete com.apple.dock.plist
2. Restart/Reboot Mac
3. Go back to ~/Library/Preferences and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to get info on the .plist, and make sure the permissions are set to Read & Write for Administrators.
4. Test and customize your dock to your liking!